# Ubuntu 14.04 Lock Screen Keyboard Error

Tags: unity, 14.04, lock-screen

After locking Ubuntu 14.04 x64 Desktop edition, the usb and built-in keyboards do not work on the login screen. When clicking on **password** area nothing happens.

But if I hit Ctrl + Alt + F1 and goes to Terminal 1, keyboard works.

I tried to restart `sudo service restart lightdm` but still the login screen password fill is acting like the keyboard is not working.

What could be causing this?

Comment: I met similar weird behaviour. I solved it adding another keyboard layout so that I get an icon in the greeter, so when issue happens, I can switch to kbd2 with the mouse then back to kbd1 and all is OK and I can login or even recover normal kbd usage. This may be related to remote sessions with vino / remmina.